# ASP.Net Core 2.2 HTML/CSS Navigation Bar Issues in Identity/Pages/Manage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been having this issue for a while. Before I had decided to recreate my project in a more current ASP.Net Core version, I was having many issues with CSS not applying to the elements I had selected or issues with HTML document margins after publishing to my Ubuntu Server. Many times I have tried creating the project using Core 2.2.3 2.2.2, Core 3 which I had trouble due to the inability to create an Identity but I would not like to mention this issue and focus on Core 2.2.

I would like to address that I know it is not the following of these issues:

- Cached CSS
- Issue With Web Browser (Edge, Explorer, Chrome, and FireFox have been tested)
- Issue with installed Core (I have reinstalled twice)
- Project Issue (A **minimum** of 20 projects have been created trying to fix this)

Unless my methods of testing are  incorrect, I am sure that these are the sources of the issue.

Having little experience in ASP.Net I have little to no clue what the issue could be but I have some ideas.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ymv1.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XEDs.jpg
(Excuse me for the incorrect usages of links, I am new to Stack Overflow)

Here is some of the information which could hint at something from the inspect element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiRgK.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMQSj.jpg

I am lost, and I have been having this problem forever. Anything will help, thank you so much.

Comment: It looks like the NAV bar is java script.  So my first question are you running the correct version of java and is java enabled in your browser on the PC.  You can open the IE on your machine and check the IE advance settings.  The default setting in a ASP.Net is the same settings your browser uses.

Comment: @jdweng I updated Flash & Java. Nothing has changed.

Comment: I asked what VERSION of java and is it enabled.  That is not what you responded.

Comment: @jdweng I kind of answered it when I explained that I updated to the latest version which would be 8u211. And yes Javascript is enabled. Also if it is the issue with Java then why is the navigation bar working on the front page but not in the Identity/Pages/Manage?

Comment: Not every webpage is the same.  ASPNet uses http request/response.  There are headers in the request that contain client properties.  The client has to properly setup the properties for the webpage to work properly.  For example ContentType specifies the browser on the client (IE, Chrome, ...).  If wrong ContentType is used the webpage may not work properly.